# Instantiate c++ sfml

Tags: c++, instance

Как мне создать функцию похожую на instantiate из юнити? У меня есть класс шарика в котором его уникальный айди, размер, цвет. Как мне создать несколько таких шариков В ПРОЦЕССЕ РАБОТЫ ПРОГРАММЫ? Вариант Ball Ball1, Ball Ball2; не подойдёт, так как для этого нужно изменить исходный код, а мне нужно что бы это можно было делать в работе программы. Как мне это реализовать? Уже второй день мучаюсь

Comment: Массив, вектор...